# docker compose pull from AWS ECR doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecr

I have problem with docker-compose (1) and docker compose (2) pull. When I try to pull images from direct repository (I use ECR), both commands (`sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml pull` and `sudo docker compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml pull`) give me following output:

```
 $ export DOCKER_REGISTRY= {{ secret path to AWS ECP }}
 $ $DOCKER_REGISTRY 
{{ secret path to AWS ECP }}
 $ sudo docker compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml pull
WARN[0000] The "DOCKER_REGISTRY" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "DOCKER_REGISTRY" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "DOCKER_REGISTRY" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
[+] Running 0/0
 ⠋ cron Pulling                                                                                         0.0s
 ⠿ db Error                                                                                             0.0s
 ⠋ traefik Pulling                                                                                      0.0s
 ⠋ web Pulling                                                                                          0.0s
WARNING: Some service image(s) must be built from source by running:
    docker compose build cron traefik web
invalid reference format
 $ sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml pull
WARNING: The DOCKER_REGISTRY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Pulling db ... done
```

In line 1 I export DOCKER_REGISTRY variable, that is using in `docker-compose.prod.yml`. In line 2 I check this variable and then run both of above commands. (2) sees all needed images in yml file, but can't pull them, because it doesn't see DOCKER_REGISTRY variable. (1) sees only db.

Part of prod.yml file:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/me-project_web:latest
    build:
      context: ./MoreEnergy
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    restart: always
    env_file: ./.env.prod
    entrypoint: sh ./entrypoint.sh
    command: gunicorn MoreEnergy.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    expose:
      - 8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    depends_on:
      - db
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.web.rule=Host(`lunev.dmitrium.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.web.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.web.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
```

I have .env.prod file with all needed variables too, but (1) and (2) don't see DOCKER_REGISTRY variable anyway.

What should I do? I'm trying to implement CI/CD using GitHub actions. In current state, docker-compose can build and push all my images to AWS ECR, but can't pull them back.

Comment: P.S. docker pull "$DOCKER_REGISTRY/repo_name_1" works fine, but I need to make pull for all repos

Comment: How did you set `DOCKER_REGISTRY` and how looks it value. Can you provide as close as possible value?

Comment: @rzlvmp `DOCKER_REGISTRY` variable is url to AWS ECR in format aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com. I've set it by using export command. I've already found solution. I will write answer for my own question right now.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was utterly stupid and simple. 10 minutes before asking the question, I've successfully started the containers, pulled by `docker pull` command before, but forgot it, because detail of success was not conspicuous. I've done this by NOT using this command with `sudo`. Yes, it is. `sudo docker compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up` and `docker compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up` (and pull) commands run correct only if you do it without root access.

Maybe it's not a common solution, and in other cases sudo is required, but not in mine.

Comment: Upd: only `docker compose` successfully complete pull and up containers. `docker-compose` still not works in my case (it it does not see other images except for db, that is not on AWS ECR), but it is not important.